# Assigning a one letter to a string variable

Tags: vba, string, excel-formula, range, excel-2010

My code :

```
Dim ws_fe As Worksheet
Set ws_fe = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("xx")

Dim ws_de As Worksheet
Set ws_de = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("xxx")

Dim a as string
a = B

ws_fe.Cells(5, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",RC[-5]-" & a & 6
```

I want to assing a range for exemple "B6", but all I get for the a value is :

- when putting a=B I get a= nothing (as in range B in excel there are no values in cells)(if I had put something in A:A he would had chosen that first value)
- when putting a="B" I get a="B"

The problem is that the R1C1 formula does not recognise only the B but "B", and that makes problems when assigning a range as this is getting "B"6 instead of B6

How can I do it so VBA recognizes correctly B only as simple string B ?

I was expecting:

```
ws_fe.Cells(5, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",RC[-5]-" & a & 6 = =if(rxcx= "" ; "" ; rxcx - B6)
```

Comment: When you put a = B, B is not a defined variable.  As a result VBA assigns it as a variant type variable.  Since B has not been assigned anything yet, it has the value of nothing hence a is nothing.  When you put a= "B", What is between quotes is your string, so a = the string B.

Comment: I am guessing here, but if you want to a variable to take on a range, you should first define the variable as a range `DIM a as Range`  then `Set a = ws_de.ws_fe.range("B6")` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work for a number of reasons.

- You're not forcing variable declaration, so when it gets to `a = B` the code happily defines B as an empty variable.
  Select *Options ~ Editor tab ~ Require Variable Declaration* and each new module will include the text *Option Explicit* at the top of your module and it will point out the error.
  [image]
- Your formula is mixing R1C1 and A1 formula referencing.  `R6C2` would work for B6 if that's the cell reference you're after.
- Your formula doesn't include a final closing bracket.

Changing the two rows to

```
a = "C2"
ws_fe.Cells(5, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",RC[-5]-R6" & a & ")"
```

will add the formula `=IF(F5="","",E5-$B$6)` to cell `J5`.

Answer (score 0):

In case  a="B"

This formula in cell H28

```
"=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",RC[-5]-R" & columns(a).column & "C6)"
```

gives the result

```
=IF(D28="","",C28-$F$2)
```

and this

```
"=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",RC[-5]-R[" & columns(a).column & "]C[6])"
```

results

```
=IF(D28="","",C28-N30)
```